# Is there any alternative to Nikon SU-800?

Tags: nikon, flash, macro-flash

I just got the kit R1 (without the SU-800) with the two flashes Nikon SB-R200.

Because now I have a D300, I will make my pictures using the integrated flash (with the provided IR converter from the R1 Kit) but a question remains to me: is there any generic brand that make a IR commander like the SU-800 (but I guess it should be cheaper).

Anybody have experience with such generic devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Debao SU-800](http://www.lightingrumours.com/debao-su-800-st-e2-have-longer-range-than-the-real-thing-4205#.U3P9BvldXzg).  Looks to be about $100, and more powerful.  [fstoppers.com has a review](http://fstoppers.com/debao-su800-flash-commander-review).

Comment: Looks to be a very good alternative. A good point is that it takes also AA batteries which are cheaper and easier to find. I found it on [this site](http://www.eachshot.com/product/debao-su-800-nikon-wireless-speedlight-commander-trigger/1841.html) for 78$ but I am waiting to have the D500 as now with D300 I still have the built-in flash (but only two groups).

Comment: I bought the Debao and I can say it is a very good alternative. Note that any other Cobra flash from Nikon who have also the Commander mode can also trig the SB-R200 (I tested with a SB-800)