# Is there a 3rd-party wireless slave for Nikon SU-4 triggering?

Tags: nikon, flash, wireless-flash, macro-flash

My question is similar to [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50277/is-there-any-alternative-to-nikon-su-800) about a generic commander for the Nikon CLS system (IR wireless flash).

Now if I want my SB-25 to be slaved by this system the Nikon SU-4 does the right job. As I am interested in saving some money for a device I would use rarely and not in complex setups (even I conceive the Nikon one is not so high): is there any "no-name" alternative to this device (the SU-4)?

I know there are many alternatives with commander/slave on radio wireless but this question focuses on the SU-4. (I have already the SB-R1 without commander, using the body integrated flash and IR diffuser.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there'd be a generic SU-4 type unit, given that all you have to buy to duplicate the function of one is a "dumb" optical slave that can connect to the SB-25's PC sync port or hotshoe, such as the slaves from Sonia or Wein.  The very inexpensive ones probably won't ignore an iTTL pre-flash like the SU-4 mode/unit does, but then the SU-4 doesn't ignore pre-flashes from a lot of P&S camera pop-up flashes.

SU-4 mode is different from CLS in that the only real communication between the camera and the flash is the sync (fire) signal.  CLS communicates a lot more, so you can have iTTL, FP, and power setting on the remote flash, which is why it's more expensive and worth getting a specialized unit.  All SU-4 can do is fire the remote flash, so any generic "dumb" optical slave can pretty much do the same thing.

Frankly, you'd probably be better off with cheap manual radio triggers. They don't cost much more, and they do not have the reliability, range, or line-of-sight restrictions that optical slaves have, particularly if you plan on using them outside in bright sunlight.

Comment: thanks for your answer, in fact the wireless radio (whole set) looks interesting but it would not be compatible with the two SB-R200 I have already. I was just looking for a possible alternative. Anyway the SU-4 is not so high price than the su-800.