# Flash that has the same "master" features as a sb-800

Tags: nikon, flash, cls, commander-mode

I previously asked [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/50277/4056) and I understand as well I can use a flash to use as a master to command the SB-R200 units.

I know the SB-800 or the alternative Debao can command 4 channels and three different groups of flashes (A, B & C).

I saw the Nikon SB-910 have exactly the same settings (4 channels + 3 groups) but it is quite expensive. On the other side, the SB-700 seems it can only controls 2 groups (A,B) instead three (I am not 100% sure, but [this page](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/flashes/sb-700-af-speedlight.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs) seems to confirm it).

Is there any other cheaper flash alternative with these settings:

- A flash (any brand but Nikon iTTl compatible)
- Compatible with Nikon CLS
- Can be Master(commander) with

  - 4 channels
  - 3 groups

I did like the Metz brand as well but did not find clear information about that specific Master setting on the models I have checked.

Comment: I don't understand the close vote. I need facts not opinions and this is not going to change (or if a new model comes later a new answer can always be added)

Comment: The rub is definitely in _"or if a new model comes later a new answer can always be added"_ — experience shows that that kind of maintenance is extremely unlikely to happen, which means that six months from now, this _might_ be the right answer and it might be misdirection with wrong advice. We're looking for questions with longer value than that.

Comment: _Plus_, this doesn't really require _expertise_ — just the ability to look at online stores.

Comment: Maybe [Why is there so much hostility to 'what should I buy' and 'shopping' questions?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3957) in our meta and [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809) on meta.SE and [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) on the stackoverflow blog can explain why any question that's basically just asking, "what should I buy?" tends to be off topic on SE. dpreview forums might be a better fit for this.

Comment: > "Plus, this doesn't really require expertise — just the ability to look at online stores." Sorry but I am not finding such features in the e-shop I was looking. I had to read all manuals of the flashes... then does not require expertise, yes in fact just experiences of other users with same needs and found the right device.

Comment: @mattdm for your first comment: That can explain why this site have so few questions. I think the "edit/community wiki" features is especially to make the questions/answer to live, and that is exactly why the excavator badge is for, is it really unwanted?

Comment: Again, experience has shown that those kind of old questions are not saved by "community wiki". As for number of questions, I'd rather have quality questions that meet the site's goals.

Comment: It's not that your question is *bad per se*. It's just off of what Stack Exchange is good at.

Answer (score 1):

For the SB-R200 units, the SU-800 will be the least expensive Nikon ($250). It is not a flash, but it is a commander. It also has a special switch in the battery compartment for the SB-R200 use.   Manual here:  http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/fjsSS00dnTJB02EH9Pd005z9n144/SB-R200_EU(En)10.pdf

There are one or two third party flashes with commander capability. I have an Aperlite YH-700N that does, for $90.  It works, however its menu for this seems very awkward compared to Nikons.

Comment: I know the SB-800 commander is probably the best match but I want to now if there is a flash that can do the same job as the flash can be also used alone (e.g. for the D500 owners).